# Add image to word document in Expo react native with doc.js

Tags: react-native, expo, docx

I would like to add an image in a Word document using [docx.js](https://docx.js.org/#/usage/images?id=intro) and I was following this [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-docx-images?file=index.tsx), but it has failed. below is my code.

```
const generateFromUrl = async () => {
 const blob = await axios(
  "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dolanmiu/docx/master/demo/images/cat.jpg"
 ).then((r) => r.blob());

 const doc = new Document({
  sections: [
    {
      children: [
        new Paragraph("Hello World"),
        new Paragraph({
          children: [
            new ImageRun({
              data: blob,
              transformation: {
                width: 100,
                height: 100,
              },
            }),
          ],
        }),
      ],
    },
  ],
});
Packer.toBase64String(doc).then((base64) => {
  const filename =
    FileSystem.documentDirectory +
    info.full_names.replaceAll(" ", "_") +
    "resume.docx";
  FileSystem.writeAsStringAsync(filename, base64, {
    encoding: FileSystem.EncodingType.Base64,
  }).then(() => {
    Sharing.shareAsync(filename);
  });
})
};
```

Below is the error.
[image]

If you have any other way to do it, that solution is also welcome.

Thank you in advance